# Sybase: Composing a WHERE for a timestamp datatype

Tags: sql, select, timestamp, sybase, where-clause

I'm trying to compose a SQL Select statement for Sybase with a Where clause on Timestamp datatype.

```
SELECT * FROM DEV.CONF WHERE LAST_UPDATE < '[some_date]'
```

- The LAST_UPDATE column is the datatype Timestamp.
- I've tried using the convert function and others but can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: So what's the problem? The format for `some_date`?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short The problem is datatype for LAST_UPDATE is a timestamp, not a datetime.  The timestamp datatype is a binary format and I want to convert strings such as '6/16/2011 4:17:29' into the datetime format.  So I get errors like "DATETIME" is not valid in the context where it is used when `SELECT * FROM REPORT.CONF WHERE LAST_UPDATE < CONVERT(DATETIME, '6/16/2011 4:17:29.463114 AM', 109)` is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the SQL standard specifies [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601) format for timestamps so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM DEV.CONF WHERE LAST_UPDATE < '2011-06-16 04:17:29.463114'
```

where you want to use "04:17:29.463114 on June 16 2011" as your timestamp.

At the database level, you should only be using ISO 8601 date and time formats unless there is a very good reason for anything else (this part is just me being a bit opinionated though :).